# How to define a global gradle path for React Native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I need react native to use a custom gradle path instead of the default one which is `%userprofile%/.gradle`. In Android Studio it's easily changed in the settings (Default settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Service directory path).

However I could not find a way for the react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved the problem by adding a symlink from .gradle to my custom gradle path by running this from an elevated command prompt:

`mklink /D C:\Users\yourusername\.gradle E:\custom\path\to\gradle`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be great if you could maybe include the commands you used to create the symlink, etc. Keep in mind others will come here looking for a solution and your "I did it" answer may not help them.

Comment: Though this symlink method will work, it's a hacky solution.  I gave an alternate answer using an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Set the environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to your custom gradle path.